# Get Rid of Spinning "Loading" Appearance on iOS Safari with SignalR

Tags: signalr

Is there any way to disable the spinning "loading" appearance of a web page that's using SignalR from a web page on Safari for iOS?  I understand that it's probably using long polling, but it makes it look like the page has never finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, there's no straight-forward work for all browser fix which is why it hasn't been fixed yet.

See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/215